# BowerStatic in Pyramid: why scripts aren't going to the end of body?

Tags: python-2.7, bower, pyramid

I am using pyramid_bowerstatic-0.3-py2.7, bowerstatic-0.8.1 in Pyramid 1.5.6 with SB Admin 2 bootstrap 3 theme (if that matters).

When including components with, e.g.

```
request.include(components, 'jquery')
```

in a normally configured view (which uses template):

```
@view_config(route_name='list', renderer='templates/list.pt', permission="view")
def list_view(self):
    request.include(components, 'jquery')
    return {'project': 'My', }
```

where (in the project __init__):

```
components = pyramid_bowerstatic.create_components('sbadmin',
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sbadmin', 'bower_components'))
```

I am getting both CSS and Javascript in the head of html. And to my understanding javascripts should go to before body ends. Also I am not sure how to control the order and maybe to add selected javascripts to the head. bowerstatic seems to follow the order of inclusion, but at the same time seems to care for dependencies.

Can't find anything on this in the documentation. What am I missing?

Comment: I have never used this package but reading the [source](https://github.com/mrijken/pyramid_bowerstatic/blob/master/pyramid_bowerstatic/__init__.py) it seems all the scripts are inserted in the header of the page and there's no way to control the position of each script. In the `create_components` method there's a `bottom` argument but I'm guessing that this only insert all scripts at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (May, 2015), it is not possible in bower_static according to the ticket:
https://github.com/faassen/bowerstatic/issues/32